# How to access the Uri of a photo taken by my own camera activity?

Tags: java, android

I've written a camera activity that takes a picture and saves it into memory, how can I access the Uri of the photo that is saved ?

Here is some code of my camera activity :

```
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        if (pictureFile == null){
            Log.d("Errore Doorbin", "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            // these lines are for the gallery to scan the SDCard manually
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
                    Uri.parse("file://"+ mediaStorageDir)));
           /* MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(CameraActivity.this,
                    new String[] { fos.toString() }, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    // code to execute when scanning is complete
                }
           });*/
           // fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("Errore Doorbin", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Errore Doorbin", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Errore Doorbin", "errore Kolli dade!" + e.getMessage()) ;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#fromFile%28java.io.File%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file that is taken by this activity is `pictureFile`, so for accessing to it's Uri you should use the Uri's function `fromFile()` like this :

`Uri photoUri = Uri.fromFile(pictureFile);`